# GNU Make with multiple options for a target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am curious if Make has a method to support multiple (independent) ways of creating the same target.  For an example, say I have two source directories: `svg_src` (containing SVG images), and `agr_src` (containing xmgrace plots).  I would like to be able to write a rule so that I don't have to bother worrying what the source is:

```
pdf_out/%.pdf : svg_src/%.svg
    rsvg-convert -f pdf -o $@ $<

pdf_out/%.eps : agr_src/%.svg
    gracebat -hdevice EPS -hardcopy $@ $<

pdf_out/%.pdf : pdf_out/%.eps
    epstopdf $<
```

However, the second `%.pdf` rule overwrites the first one, as opposed to supplying another option.

Is there a way of accomplishing this with Make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have provided already the correct solution. In contrast to your assumption, the second rule does not override the first one, because it has (due to the source directory) different dependencies.

Consider the following example, where I've used your Makefile and your directory structure with `a.svg` in svg_src, and `b.svg` in agr_src:

```
#> make -n pdf_out/a.pdf pdf_out/b.pdf
rsvg-convert -f pdf -o pdf_out/a.pdf svg_src/a.svg
gracebat -hdevice EPS -hardcopy pdf_out/b.eps agr_src/b.svg
epstopdf pdf_out/b.eps
rm pdf_out/b.eps
#>
```

I guess, this is exactly what you want.

Comment: wow.. I tried an example test, but didn't bother separating it into directories (foo : bar; foo : baz)... apparently the directories make the difference.  Thanks for pointing that out.